# How to pass parameters in nested argo steps?

Tags: argo-workflows

I am trying to pass parameters from an outer step template to an inner step template in argo. Below is my workflow definition.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: fanout-
spec:
  templates:
    - name: process-workflows
      steps:
        - - name: fanout
            template: fan-out
        - - name: fanout-step
            template: parallel-process
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: batch
                  value: '{{item}}'
            withParam: '{{steps.fanout.outputs.result}}'
    - name: fan-out
      script:
        name: main
        image: 'node:lts-alpine3.14'
        command:
          - node
        resources: {}
        source: |
          inputlist = JSON.parse({{=toJson(workflow.parameters.inputlist)}})
          fanout = {{workflow.parameters.fanout}}
          var i,j, result=[];
          for (i = 0,j = inputlist.length; i < j; i += fanout) {
              result.push(inputlist.slice(i, i + fanout));
          }
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
    - name: parallel-process
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: batch
      steps:
        - - name: actualprocessor
            template: process
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: input
                  value: {{inputs.parameters.batch}}
        - - name: aggregate-result
            template: aggregate
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: aggregate
                  value: {{steps.actualprocessor.outputs.parameters.res}}
    - name: process
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: input
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: res
            valueFrom:
              path: /tmp/res.txt
      script:
        name: main
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
        source: |
          sleep 5
          echo 'awakened...'
          echo processing-{{=toJson(inputs.parameters.input)}}
          echo {{=toJson(inputs.parameters.input)}} > /tmp/res.txt
    - name: aggregate
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: aggregate
      container:
        name: main
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
          - '-c'
        args:
          - 'echo received {{inputs.parameters.aggregate}}'
  entrypoint: process-workflows
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: inputlist
        value: |
          [
            {"k" : "v1", "a" : [{ "k": true}]},
            {"k" : "v2", "a" : [{ "k": true}]}
          ]
      - name: fanout
        value: '1'
```

Use case:

The fanout-step step (outer step) uses parallel-process template (inner step). It provides a `batch` argument to the parallel-process template. The parallel-process template needs to provide the value of `batch` to the `input` parameters in the target step.

Issue: The input parameter inside the actualprocessor step is empty. I can see that the batch input param is getting populated correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The only problem I can find is that some of the templates aren't quoted. Is this the exact YAML you're using?

Comment: Yes, This template can be submitted via argo UI.

Comment: You mean `{{inputs.parameters.batch}}` is empty when the `actualprocessor` starts? can you try `"{{inputs.parameters.batch}}"`? i remember having issues with the parameter parser when it was not encased in string

Comment: Thanks, @TomSlabbaert The quote seems to be the missing part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by encasing the parameters in quotes. Thanks to Tom Slabbaer for pointing it out.

Below is the working template.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: fanout-
spec:
  templates:
    - name: process-workflows
      steps:
        - - name: fanout
            template: fan-out
        - - name: fanout-step
            template: parallel-process
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: batch
                  value: '{{item}}'
            withParam: '{{steps.fanout.outputs.result}}'
    - name: fan-out
      script:
        name: main
        image: 'node:lts-alpine3.14'
        command:
          - node
        resources: {}
        source: |
          inputlist = JSON.parse({{=toJson(workflow.parameters.inputlist)}})
          fanout = {{workflow.parameters.fanout}}
          var i,j, result=[];
          for (i = 0,j = inputlist.length; i < j; i += fanout) {
              result.push(inputlist.slice(i, i + fanout));
          }
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
    - name: parallel-process
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: batch
      steps:
        - - name: actualprocessor
            template: process
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: input
                  value: "{{inputs.parameters.batch}}"
        - - name: aggregate-result
            template: aggregate
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: aggregate
                  value: "{{steps.actualprocessor.outputs.parameters.res}}"
    - name: process
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: input
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: res
            valueFrom:
              path: /tmp/res.txt
      script:
        name: main
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
        source: |
          sleep 5
          echo 'awakened...'
          echo processing-{{=toJson(inputs.parameters.input)}}
          echo {{=toJson(inputs.parameters.input)}} > /tmp/res.txt
    - name: aggregate
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: aggregate
      container:
        name: main
        image: 'alpine:latest'
        command:
          - sh
          - '-c'
        args:
          - 'echo received {{inputs.parameters.aggregate}}'
  entrypoint: process-workflows
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: inputlist
        value: |
          [
            {"k" : "v1", "a" : [{ "k": true}]},
            {"k" : "v2", "a" : [{ "k": true}]}
          ]
      - name: fanout
        value: '1'
```

Comment: can you answer this one -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195759/how-to-pass-paramters-to-argo-workflow-api